# Convert Timestamp to minutes in Oracle after a subtraction

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the minute value from a Timestamp after a subtraction

First I made a subtraction:

Current Time - Target Time(INSP_FIN_DT)

```
(
  TO_TIMESTAMP(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - 
  TO_TIMESTAMP(INSP_FIN_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
 ) AS REST_TIME
```

the output:

> +00 00:09:44.000000

What I need:

> 09

I already tried

`SELECT SUBSTR(REST_TIME, 7,2)`

But the return is ever 00, even If I convert it to Char like:

`SELECT SUBSTR(TO_CHAR(REST_TIME),7,2)`

How can I solve it by query?

Comment: have you seen the solutions here? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53924/how-do-i-get-the-difference-in-minutes-from-2-timestamp-columns

Comment: You can `extract(hour from ...)`. But why are you converting `sysdate` to a string and then to a timestamp, instead of using `systimestamp`? And are you really storing dates as strings in your `INSP_FIN_DT` column - if so why isn't that stored as a proper date?

Comment: Thank you for the tips @AlexPoole, I've edited with the solution you suggested.

Comment: If the difference was 1 hour and 9 minutes, would you expect the output to be 69 minutes or 9 minutes?

Comment: For the current implementation, I just need minutes because I'll never have more than a hour.
I''ll insert a self-answer according you said @MT0, thank you

Comment: _"I'll never have more than a hour. "_    Famous last words.  I've just retired from a 40+ year career in IT, and can attest that the landscape is littered with code that had to be hurriedly modified to account for a situation that the original design said "would never occur".

Comment: @EdStevens you are correct! that's why I wrote complete solution as self-answer in order to prevent future issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my current implementation, I'll never have more than a hour, in this case I used the bellow solution:

```
SYSTIMESTAMP - TO_TIMESTAMP(INSP_FIN_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS REST_TIME
```

Select..

```
EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM REST_TIME) AS REST_MINUTES
```

In case of more than 60 minutes, I should use:

```
(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM REST_TIME) * 60)  
+ EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM REST_TIME) AS REST_MINUTES
```

Answer (score 1):

Information here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53924/how-do-i-get-the-difference-in-minutes-from-2-timestamp-columns

```
select
  round(
    (SYSDATE - cast(<other_timestamp> as date))
    * 24 * 60
  ) as diff_minutes
from <some_table>;
```

Comment: Instead of `cast(current_timestamp as date)` use simply `SYSDATE`